# Not able to start minikube on centOS7

Tags: kubernetes, centos7, minikube

I am using CentOS Linux 7 (Core) and tried to install minikube and followed all steps provided at [Install Minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/).

I have alo installed virtualbox on CentOS7 which can be seen logs installed correctly when started minikube but its failing, please seee full error logs.

can someone please help what I am missing.

Kubectl is also installed but could not connect with server as Minikube in not starting..

```
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.4", GitCommit:"c27b913fddd1a6c480c229191a087698aa92f0b1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-02-28T13:37:52Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

**Minikube start command error logs**

```
minikube v0.35.0 on linux (amd64)
>   Creating virtualbox VM (CPUs=2, Memory=2048MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
@   Downloading Minikube ISO ...
 184.42 MB / 184.42 MB [============================================] 100.00% 0s
-   "minikube" IP address is 192.168.99.102
-   Configuring Docker as the container runtime ...
-   Preparing Kubernetes environment ...
@   Downloading kubeadm v1.13.4
@   Downloading kubelet v1.13.4
-   Pulling images required by Kubernetes v1.13.4 ...
-   Launching Kubernetes v1.13.4 using kubeadm ...
!   Error starting cluster: kubeadm init:
sudo /usr/bin/kubeadm init --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--data-minikube --ignore-preflight-errors=Port-10250 --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-scheduler.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-apiserver.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-controller-manager.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-etcd.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=Swap --ignore-preflight-errors=CRI

[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.13.4
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
        [WARNING Service-Docker]: docker service is not enabled, please run 'systemctl enable docker.service'
        [WARNING Swap]: running with swap on is not supported. Please disable swap
[preflight] Pulling images required for setting up a Kubernetes cluster
[preflight] This might take a minute or two, depending on the speed of your internet connection
[preflight] You can also perform this action in beforehand using 'kubeadm config images pull'
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet environment file with flags to file "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env"
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet configuration to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
[kubelet-start] Activating the kubelet service
[certs] Using certificateDir folder "/var/lib/minikube/certs/"
[certs] Generating "front-proxy-ca" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "front-proxy-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "etcd/ca" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "etcd/healthcheck-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "apiserver-etcd-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "etcd/server" certificate and key
[certs] etcd/server serving cert is signed for DNS names [minikube localhost] and IPs [192.168.99.102 127.0.0.1 ::1]
[certs] Generating "etcd/peer" certificate and key
[certs] etcd/peer serving cert is signed for DNS names [minikube localhost] and IPs [192.168.99.102 127.0.0.1 ::1]
[certs] Using existing ca certificate authority
[certs] Using existing apiserver certificate and key on disk
[certs] Generating "apiserver-kubelet-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "sa" key and public key
[kubeconfig] Using kubeconfig folder "/etc/kubernetes"
[kubeconfig] Writing "admin.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "kubelet.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "controller-manager.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "scheduler.conf" kubeconfig file
[control-plane] Using manifest folder "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-apiserver"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-controller-manager"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-scheduler"
[etcd] Creating static Pod manifest for local etcd in "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[wait-control-plane] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests". This can take up to 4m0s
[kubelet-check] Initial timeout of 40s passed.
error execution phase wait-control-plane: couldn't initialize a Kubernetes cluster

Unfortunately, an error has occurred:
        timed out waiting for the condition

This error is likely caused by:
        - The kubelet is not running
        - The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled)

If you are on a systemd-powered system, you can try to troubleshoot the error with the following commands:
        - 'systemctl status kubelet'
        - 'journalctl -xeu kubelet'

Additionally, a control plane component may have crashed or exited when started by the container runtime.
To troubleshoot, list all containers using your preferred container runtimes CLI, e.g. docker.
Here is one example how you may list all Kubernetes containers running in docker:
        - 'docker ps -a | grep kube | grep -v pause'
        Once you have found the failing container, you can inspect its logs with:
        - 'docker logs CONTAINERID'

: Process exited with status 1

*   Sorry that minikube crashed. If this was unexpected, we would love to hear from you:
-   https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new
```

Comment: from the first glance, did you try those hints: 
`[WARNING Service-Docker]: docker service is not enabled, please run 'systemctl enable docker.service'`
`[WARNING Swap]: running with swap on is not supported. Please disable swap`

Answer (score 1):

Kubelet will fail to start after v1.8.0 if swap is enabled. You could overwrite this in your Kubelet configuration.

Reference:

1. Update Notice: https://github.com/apprenda/kismatic/blob/master/docs/upgrade/v1.6.0/kubelet-swap.md
2. Reasons for disabling swap: https://serverfault.com/questions/881517/why-disable-swap-on-kubernetes